# Order a column by low, medium, high?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So, I have this:

```
select ticket_trackingno, ticket_title, ticket_priority_id, ticket_status_id
from hd_tickets
where ticket_priority_id <> 'None'
and ticket_status_id = 'Assigned'
order by ticket_priority_id desc
```

With this, my ticket_priority_id column gets sorted as med, low, high. What I want is low, med, high. I was wondering how I might go about doing that?

Comment: What do you mean by med, low, high? order by will order in numeric or character order

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE ticket_priority_id
         WHEN 'low' THEN 1
         WHEN 'med' THEN 2
         WHEN 'high' THEN 3 END
```