# Ruby - sort by specific data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not wanting to sort by ascending or descending order. In my ruby on rails application, I have a table and each row contains either "High", "Medium", "Low", "Informational".

How can I sort in that order using something like Issues.all.order(['high','medium','low','informational']).

Can I do something like that with rails?

Comment: thanks. didn't run across that. but that's exactly what I'm looking for. Going there for my answer. thanks again!

Comment: refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185792/order-a-column-by-low-medium-high

Comment: Hi, please mention the column name which contains the "High"/"Medium"/"Low"/"Informational". Thanks